# How to 'flatten' the result in Neo4j cypher?

Tags: neo4j

I have the following tables (similar to Northwind sample database):

```
Employee->OrdersWithDetails<-Products tables
Employee(includes employee-manager relationship with 4 levels)
Employee->EmployeeLvls - links employee's level with specific attributes tied to his level
OrdersWithDetails combines Orders & OrderDetails into one set.
```

For each employee, I’m trying to display employee's orders and $$; i.e. OrderId, SoldAmt **and** employee’s managers UP the line.

There should be a SINGLE line for the combination of employee and OrderId, but so far I was only able to display multiple lines; for each level -additional line with manager's name is added.

Here is my cypher
*

```
 MATCH (e:Employees)-[:JOB_LEVEL_OF]->(el:EmployeeLvls)
where e.Name ="Vidur Luthra" //limiting to a single employee
MATCH (p:Products)-[:PRODUCT]->(owd:OrdersWithDetails)<-[:SOLD]-(e)-[:REPORTS_TO*0..4]->(m:Employees)-[:JOB_LEVEL_OF]->(el_m:EmployeeLvls)
WHERE m.EmployeeId <> e.EmployeeId  //excluding employee
RETURN e.Name as Employee ,owd.OrderId 
,SUM(owd.ProductQuantity*p.UnitPrice) as SoldAmt //display manager's names based on their level:
,(CASE WHEN m.EmployeeLvlId = e.EmployeeLvlId - 1 THEN m.Name ELSE '-' END) as Manager_1_LevelAbove
,(CASE WHEN m.EmployeeLvlId = e.EmployeeLvlId - 2 THEN m.Name ELSE '-' END) as Manager_2_LevelsAbove
,(CASE WHEN m.EmployeeLvlId = e.EmployeeLvlId - 3 THEN m.Name ELSE '-' END) as Manager_3_LevelsAbove
```

*

Here is my outcome:
[current result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rwizq.jpg) or

```
Employee|OrderId|SoldAmt |Manager_1_LevelAbove|Manager_2_LevelsAbove| Manager_3_LevelsAbove
Vidur Luthra|94 |733.49  |James Kramer        |                     | 
Vidur Luthra|94 |733.49  |                    |                     | Ken Sanchez
Vidur Luthra|94 |733.49  |                    |Jossef Goldberg      |
```

Here is my desired outcome:
[desired result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mXZL2.jpg) or

```
Employee|OrderId|SoldAmt |Manager_1_LevelAbove|Manager_2_LevelsAbove| Manager_3_LevelsAbove
Vidur Luthra|94 |733.49  |James Kramer        |Jossef Goldberg      | Ken Sanchez
```

What should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that the best way to do this would be to define a variable for the part of the path that you care about and then use that path:

```
MATCH
  (e:Employees)-[:JOB_LEVEL_OF]->(el:EmployeeLvls)
WHERE e.Name ="Vidur Luthra" //limiting to a single employee
MATCH
  (p:Products)-[:PRODUCT]->(owd:OrdersWithDetails)<-[:SOLD]-(e),
  reporting_path=(e)-[:REPORTS_TO*0..4]->(m:Employees)
  (m)-[:JOB_LEVEL_OF]->(el_m:EmployeeLvls)
WHERE
  NOT((m)-[:REPORTS_TO]->()) AND
  m.EmployeeId <> e.EmployeeId  //excluding employee
RETURN
  e.Name as Employee,
  owd.OrderId,
  SUM(owd.ProductQuantity * p.UnitPrice) as SoldAmt,
  (nodes(reporting_path)[0]).Name AS Manager_1_LevelAbove,
  (nodes(reporting_path)[1]).Name AS Manager_2_LevelAbove,
  (nodes(reporting_path)[2]).Name AS Manager_3_LevelAbove
```

Note here that I put in a `WHERE` clause for `NOT((m)-[:REPORTS_TO]->())`.  This means that if Jim reports to Sally who reports to Bill and Bill reports to nobody, we're only going to `MATCH` on the path between Jim and Bill, not the one between Jim and Sally.  That way we don't get duplicates like you're seeing.

Comment: There might be an off-by-one error here, but I think that the principle here should be good

Comment: Brian, your suggestion solves my problem but only theoretically, Practically, I need to be able to show or at least to export, the result into excel. As you can see from the attached picture it is not a desired result.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand.  Are you saying that my solution returns multiple results per employee?

Comment: [link to the result](http://klionsky.org/images/shared/2015_12_28/Capture3.jpg). @Brian, I'm not able to save that result into excel as a spreadsheet- please see my original request

Comment: Oh, right, I see.  That should just adding a `.name` on there.  You may or may not have to surround the object with parenthesis first, so I've added them into my answer to be safe.

Comment: if I omit parentheses - cypher complains, when I run query as  you suggested I get nulls in all Manager fields.

Comment: please see here: 
[link](http://klionsky.org/images/shared/2015_12_28/Capture4.jpg)

Comment: Right, that's probably because I used a lower-case `n` (which is the usual Cypher convention).  I changed it to uppercase, so try that.

Comment: Yes!!! That is the winner! 
Could you please again explain how NOT((m)-[:REPORTS_TO]->()) works? why is it to -->()

Comment: That is saying that we only want paths where `m` doesn't report to anybody else (the `()` matches any node, regardless of label or properties.  You could make it `(:Employees)` instead, if you wanted to)

Comment: I also need to display the properties of (el_m:EmployeeLvls) for each manager (e.g. JobTitle) . Right now, I can only do that for the highest manager level only  but not of those between ( I guess, the condition `NOT((m)-[:REPORTS_TO]->())` kicks in). How can I do that?

Comment: You should be able to add columns and reference `JobTitle` like `Name` for the job titles of those managers

Comment: Ah, I see.  I just added another answer because it won't fit in the comments.  It `UNWIND`s the nodes from the path and then `MATCH`es on them before `collect`ing again

Answer (score 0):

Another answer to address your comment:

```
MATCH
  (e:Employees)-[:JOB_LEVEL_OF]->(el:EmployeeLvls)
WHERE e.Name ="Vidur Luthra" //limiting to a single employee
MATCH
  (p:Products)-[:PRODUCT]->(owd:OrdersWithDetails)<-[:SOLD]-(e),
  reporting_path=(e)-[:REPORTS_TO*0..4]->(m:Employees)
WHERE
  NOT((m)-[:REPORTS_TO]->()) AND
  m.EmployeeId <> e.EmployeeId  //excluding employee


WITH e, owd, p, nodes(reporting_path) AS managers
UNWIND managers AS manager
MATCH (manager)-[:JOB_LEVEL_OF]->(el_m:EmployeeLvls)

WITH e, owd, p, collect({Name: manager.Name, JobTitle: el_m.JobTitle}) AS managers

RETURN
  e.Name as Employee,
  owd.OrderId,
  SUM(owd.ProductQuantity * p.UnitPrice) as SoldAmt,
  (managers[0]).Name AS Manager_1_LevelAbove,
  (managers[0]).JobTitle AS Manager_1_JobTitle,
  (managers[1]).Name AS Manager_2_LevelAbove,
  (managers[1]).JobTitle AS Manager_2_JobTitle,
  (managers[2]).Name AS Manager_3_LevelAbove
  (managers[2]).JobTitle AS Manager_3_JobTitle
```